# Assign invalidValue to Enum variable (why is this not throwing an Exception?)

Tags: c#, enums, casting

I was writing some generic enum casting logic, and I came across a strange phenomenon with `Enum.ToObject` method:

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    public enum FixedSet
    {
        Value1 = 1,
        Value2 = 2,
        Value3 = 3

    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {

        try
        {
            var intVal = 123;
            FixedSet actual = (FixedSet)Enum.ToObject(typeof(FixedSet), intVal);
            Assert.Fail("Thought an exception should have occured");
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            //should have thrown an exception
        }
    }
}
```

```

I would expect this to throw some kind of exception, since 123 is not a value of the given enum type, however, I am able to set it as the value of this FixedSet variable.

Why is this allowed? I always assumed this should fail since C# is a strongly typed language, and this is a strongly defined enum...

Comment: No, it does not work like this. `Enum` is its underlying type.

Comment: copy paste the code, you'll see it fails. the question is "Why is this not throwing an exception"

Comment: [Define "fail".](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Xt38n6) You mean it gets to the assertion?

Comment: I mean the fact that it fails is ok. Enums do not work like  this. Sorry for misunderstanding: I gave you the answer below.

Comment: Fail as in this is a unit test, it either fails or passes

Comment: @NathanTregillus Ahhh gotcha. I'd call it a poorly defined unit test though, if it only succeeds when the language implementation is wrong.

Comment: it was just a simple way of testing my misunderstanding of Enums. I was under the misunderstanding that Enum "has a" int variable, when in reality Enum "is a" integer.

Comment: i misunderstood because you can change the data type  of an enum with an attribute (e.g. byte, flag, etc)

Comment: Updated my answer with some information.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to ISO IEC 23270 (2006):

> In particular, any value of the underlying type of an enum can be cast
>   to the enum type, and is a distinct valid value of that enum type.

Enumeration does not "inherit" from underlying type (it's only a syntax). According to the same ISO, enumeration implicitly inherits from [`System.Enum`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`System.ValueType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.valuetype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

> The type `System.Enum` is the abstract base class of all enum types (this is distinct and different from the underlying type of the enum
>   type)
>
> Note that `System.Enum` is not itself an enum-type. Rather, it is a
>   class-type from which all enum-types are derived. The type `System.Enum`
>   inherits from the type `System.ValueType` (§11.1.1), which, in turn,
>   inherits from type `object`

If you want to check if enum's value is valid in "common" sense, you can use [`Enum.IsDefined`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.isdefined%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

Comment: ah, so the fact that the default datatype of an enum is an int, based upon inheritance it has to follow the parent classes requirements. that makes sense. thanks for clarifying "it doesn't work like this" this is more constructive

Comment: @NathanTregillus no, enum does not "inherit" from int. I'll update my answer in a second.